# facebook like for unity android

Tags: unity, android, facebook

Is there a way to add a like button which links to my page for my android game which I made in unity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Like button yourself and Open a page on it's click. To open external links in browser, you can use [Application.OpenURL()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html).

In this method the user have to like the page from the browser itself. I don't think there's any way by which you can make him like it from the game itself.

Comment: ok thanks and another question is there a way to link the game to installed fb application and post score updates on user behalf when the user clicks share button?

Comment: Well, you should post a different question for that. Anyways if you just want to post on user's wall, check facebook sdk for unity - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity